# Query to pick a column which ends with

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need a query which looks for a specific column in the different tables (each has its own unique name for the column, which I will add manually in the code) and check in that specific column whether the integer ends with `8`. If it does, then select the row’s `price` value and “Id” and `description`.
Thanks

Comment: I specified “more than one table with unique column name” because I use more than one table, so if anyone has an example please take data from 2 different tables which has different column name. If this column value ends with “8” then select...

Comment: Is the columnName same in all the tables ,which you want the ends with 8 query on?

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 1):

Try below solution. It uses `information_schema.columns` to filter by column names. Using data from that table, we then build a query (dynamic SQL) and at the end we execute it with `exec` fucntion.

```
-- Test tables
create table tbl1 (id int, description varchar(50), price float, specialColumn int)
create table tbl2 (id int, description varchar(50), price float, otheerSpecialColumn int)

insert into tbl1 values
(1, 'asdf', 20, 8),
(2, 'asdf', 20, 228),
(3, 'asdf', 20, 32);
insert into tbl2 values
(1, 'asdf', 20, 38),
(2, 'asdf', 20, 2228),
(3, 'asdf', 20, 15);

-- Query
declare @sql varchar(max);
select @sql = string_agg('select * from ' + table_name + ' where ' + column_name + ' % 10 = 8', '; ')
from information_schema.columns
where charindex('special', column_name) > 0

exec(@sql)
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be done easily by using the modulus operator `%` and `union all` to concatenate the results together.

Note: If the integer value to be checked could be negative, then take `abs()` before taking modulus.

**Test Dataset**

```
use [testdb];
GO

-- 1st table    
if OBJECT_ID('testdb..table1') is not null
    drop table testdb..table1;
create table [table1] (
    [Id] int,
    [price] money,
    [description] varchar(max),
    [name_1] int  -- the value to be checked
)
insert into [table1]([Id], [price], [description], name_1)
values (11,1.1,'desc of id=11',8),
       (12,1.2,'desc of id=12',0),
       (13,1.3,'desc of id=13',18),
       (14,1.4,'desc of id=14',80);

-- 2nd table
if OBJECT_ID('testdb..table2') is not null
    drop table testdb..table2;
create table [table2] (
    [Id] int,
    [price] money,
    [description] varchar(max),
    [name_2] int  -- the value to be checked
)
insert into [table2]([Id], [price], [description], name_2)
values (21,2.1,'desc of id=21',8),
       (22,2.2,'desc of id=22',0),
       (23,2.3,'desc of id=23',18),
       (24,2.4,'desc of id=24',80);
```

**Solution**

```
select [Id], [price], [description]
from [table1]
where [name_1] % 10 = 8  -- enter name_1 manually
union all
select [Id], [price], [description]
from [table2]
where [name_2] % 10 = 8  -- enter name_2 manually
```

**Results**

```
| Id | price  | description   |
|----|--------|---------------|
| 11 | 1.1000 | desc of id=11 |
| 13 | 1.3000 | desc of id=13 |
| 21 | 2.1000 | desc of id=21 |
| 23 | 2.3000 | desc of id=23 |
```

Tested on SQL Server 2017 (docker image on debian 10)

Answer (score 0):

I would write this as:

```
select id, price, description
from ((select id, price, description, specific1
       from table1
      ) union all
      (select id, price, description, specific2
       from table2
      ) 
     ) t
where specific1 % 10 = 8;
```

You say that the column you are testing is an integer.  If it is really a string (even one composed only of digits), then use `where specific1 like '%8'`.